# Apple Push Notifications using Sandbox server and SNS

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I am in the midst of developing an iOS app that will incorporate push notifications.

We have decided to use the push notifications capabilities offered by Amazon's SNS.

We believe that we have configured everything correctly for Apple's Sandbox environment.

Using both backend / webapp events and the SNS console we are able to generate push notifications - however, the push notifications that make it to the iOS are few and far between.

In other words, sometimes it works great and then 2 minutes later, no messages are delivered.  Other times, it takes 10 messages before 1 is delivered and finally there are periods of time when no messages are delivered.

I think the problem is with Apple's Sandbox server and not with the SNS service or my code, but wanted to see if others had faced similar issues.

Answer (score 1):

I use exactly the same set up and have no trouble with anything, the push works as soon as it is sent from the server. We also have it set up to send one at the same time everyday, and it sends it right on the dot at the same time every time.

Comment: Thanks - and to be clear you are using Apple's Sandbox server and using  the topic capabilities within SNS?